# Docker not loading any dynamic libraries

Tags: php, docker

I've got a container for a customer tracking service I'm working on, and it needed a custom `php.ini` for `openssl` certification to connect to `netsuite`.

However at the moment I added this `ini` file, Docker went off and decided it didn't want to have php extensions anymore.

They're all enabled in the ini, for all intents and purposes the ini is the same as it was, only with a new cacert path in it.

However when `docker-compose up --build` is run, it outputs to the terminal window the following:

```
    php_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.150.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
php_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.150.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/bz2' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/bz2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/curl' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/curl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ftp' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ftp: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/fileinfo' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/fileinfo: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/gd' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/gd: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/intl' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/imap' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/imap: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mbstring' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mbstring: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mysqli' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/openssl' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/openssl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_mysql' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlite' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/soap' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/soap: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/gd.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mysqli.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/zip.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/zip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/bz2' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/bz2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/curl' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/curl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ftp' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ftp: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/fileinfo' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/fileinfo: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/gd' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/gd: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/intl' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/imap' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/imap: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mbstring' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mbstring: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mysqli' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/openssl' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/openssl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_mysql' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlite' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/soap' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/soap: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/gd.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mysqli.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
php_1  | <br />
php_1  | <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/zip.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/zip.so: cannot op[Fri Jun 11 10:05:25.655788 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.0.33 configured -- resuming normal operations
php_1  | [Fri Jun 11 10:05:25.655869 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND
```

edit; Dockerfile below

```
    FROM php:7.0-apache

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions curl imap

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
        openssl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers
```

I've no idea what has changed, the directory for the extensoions is present, but empty. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: "the ini is the same as it was": you were already using a custom **php.ini** before ? Could you share the **Dockerfile** ? It will help as your issue is related to image building.

Comment: There wasn't a php.ini earleir as far as I'm aware, updated question with dockerfile

Comment: Is your **Dockerfile** complete ? I don't see anything related to the **php.ini** ? Anyway I think you provided a **php.ini** which activates multiple extensions that aren't installed based on your **Dockerfile**.

Comment: The docker-compose puts the php.ini in place and shelling into the container and running php --ini shows its being read. Even the extensions that ARE in the dockerfile aren't being loaded, like curl and zip.

Comment: Okay, fine for the **Compose** part. But you are wrong by saying that *curl* and *zip* are installed, you only installed the system packages, not the PHP extensions !

Comment: Oh! I was unaware. I'm still fairly new to docker, how would I go about installing the extentions in the dockerfile?

Comment: You can use the `docker-php-ext-*` scripts as you already did. I like to use [this tool](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) which installs system packages + PHP extensions, it will be easier, especially if you're beginning with **Docker**.

Answer (score -1):

Your **php.ini** lists extensions that have not been installed in the container. In the **Dockerfile** you installed **system packages** which are dependencies to the PHP extensions but you need to install both.

Example to install `zip` on **PHP** < 7.3:

```
RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

---

To get a compatible **php.ini** file you can copy one from your base image like so:

```sh
docker create --rm --name php_base php:7.0-apache
docker cp php_base:$(docker exec php_base env | grep PHP_INI_DIR | cut -d'=' -f2)/php.ini-production ./php.ini
docker stop php_base
```

You then have a **php.ini** file in your current directory, you can modify it for your needs.

---

Installing **PHP** extensions can be hard as it depends on the **PHP** version, image and **Linux** flavour. I like to use [mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) which makes it very easy.

Comment: I added that extension installer and gave it curl and imap to install as a test, and bafflingly, the problem is persisting! both are showing up as not present!

Comment: Your main issue must come from your **php.ini** file. Where did you get it from ? If you can share the part of the file about extensions, maybe that would help.

Comment: My php.ini file is the standard example production file that is downloaded with php. the only change I made was the path to cacert.pem for docker.

Comment: Okay but the standard Docker PHP images do not contain as much extensions as a standard non-Docker installation. An option is to take a **php.ini** from a PHP image. Check my updated answer.